# List operation on specific elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's consider two tables given by

```
T1 = Table[{i,j,f1[i,j]},{i,0,2},{j,0,3}];
T2 = Table[{i,j,f2[i,j]},{i,0,2},{j,0,3}];
```

The functions `f1` and `f2` are expensive to compute, so that I want to compute the tables `T1` and `T2` only one time.
I now want to obtain the table `T3` defined as

```
T3 = Table[{i,j,f1[i,j] f2[i,j]},{i,0,2},{j,0,3}];
```

However, as I already know `T1` and `T2`, I want to estimate `T3` without any reevaluation of `f1` and `f2`, but using only operations on the already known tables `T1` and `T2`.

How would you perform such an operation on the lists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply:

```
T3 = T1;

T3[[All, All, 3]] *= T2[[All, All, 3]];

T3
```

Reference [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and [`TimesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TimesBy.html).

Although I strongly prefer the method above over it*, simply as an illustration of other methods you could also use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html), along with a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) using [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html):

```
Apply[{#, #2, #3*#6} &, Join[T1, T2, 3], {2}]
```

---

***** The first reason to prefer the first method is that it will not unpack a packed array, therefore with packed numeric data it can be *much* faster than alternatives such as `Apply` or `Replace`.  The second reason, which I outlined in my answer to the marked duplicate, is the consistency of using `Part` for these operations.  Third is the ability to make in-place modifications when desired, saving memory.

Comment: Anyone who wishes to add another method to this Wiki answer please feel free.

Comment: Thank you. How would you have handled the simpler case where the tables are given by
`T1 = Flatten[Table[{i,j,f1[i,j]},{i,0,2},{j,0,3}],1]` ?

Comment: @jibe Just change the second line to `T3[[All, 3]] *= T2[[All, 3]];`  Once you understand `Part` this will make sense. :-)  There are many other ways, e.g. what chris just posted, but this one is usually faster, and IMHO easier to read once you are familiar with `Part`.  Please see my answer to the linked (duplicate) question for a longer explanation.

Comment: @jibe Thanks for the Accept.  I added a second method to this answer which is perhaps a little easier to generalize, but which will not perform as well.  I still recommend the first method.

Comment: The duplicate is now in my bookmarks ! ;-) A last question... If I get rid of the `;` in the second line `T3[[All, All, 3]] *= T2[[All, All, 3]];`, Mathematica displays some strange intermediate expressions which do not correspond to the actual content of `T3`. What is the origin of this display which gives rise to confusion ?

Comment: @jibe The output of `T3[[All, All, 3]] *= T2[[All, All, 3]]` should be simply the content of the third column of each element of the final `T3` tensor.  Are you sure the content is different?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I would have naively expected the output of this command to be the entire and full `T3` tensor and not just the third column. This _limited_ display made me believe that Mathemetica had misdone the affectation. Thanks again for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Well just to offer another option:

```
  MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #1[[3]] #2[[3]]} &, {T1, T2}, 2]
```

Comment: chris, there is nothing *wrong* with this but I find the combination of `Slot` and `Part` hard to read.  I added another form to the other answer that I find clearer.  Perhaps you will find it of interest.

Comment: I did not know Join had second argument so yes thank you.